# QTcpSocket - How to send two numbers

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

**Client** Application sends two (ushort) numbers via QTcpSocket to the server:

```
ushort MessageId = 4;
ushort MessageSize = 0;
socket->write((const char*) &MessageId, sizeof(ushort));
socket->write((const char*) &MessageSize, sizeof(ushort));
socket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

**Server** Application receives the 4 bytes long message and puts it into a QByteArray buffer then decodes the numbers:

```
int bytes = socket->bytesAvailable();
QByteArray buffer = socket->read(bytes)

const char * messageIdBytes = buffer.mid(0, 2);
ushort messageId = (ushort)(*messageIdBytes);

const char * messageSizeBytes = buffer.mid(2, 4);
ushort messageSize = (ushort)(*messageSizeBytes );

qDebug() << QString("MessageId Bits: [%1], Value: [%2].").arg(QString::number(messageId, 2), QString::number(messageId));
qDebug() << QString("MessageSize Bits: [%1], Value: [%2].").arg(QString::number(messageSize, 2), QString::number(messageSize));
```

This gives the following server output: (I added the spaces for readability)

```
MessageId Bits: [1111 1111 1101 1101], Value: [65501].
MessageSize Bits: [1111 1111 1101 1101], Value: [65501].
```

- Problem: the server output should receive MessageId 4 and MessageSize 0.
- Observation: sending different values from the client doessn't even affect the server output. It's always that weird number 65501..
- Interesting: it does work however if I only write **one** number instead of two!

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output if you `qDebug() << buffer;` after 'socket->read(bytes)' ?  although I think the missing `;` dose not cause a compile error ;D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending raw numbers is never a good idea. Reasons for why this could be going wrong are:

- Desychronisation
- Endianess
- Parsing errors
- ...

Best practice in Qt is to use `QDataStream` to send and receive data:

Client code:

```
QDataStream stream(socket);
stream << MessageId << MessageSize;
```

Server code:

```
QDataStream stream(socket);
ushort MessageId, MessageSize;
stream.startTransaction();
stream >> MessageId >> MessageSize;
if(stream.commitTransaction())
    qDebug() << "Worked:" << MessageId << MessageSize;
else
    qDebug() << "Error:" << stream.status();
```

You can read more about QDataStream and read transactions at the [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#using-read-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading junk data, look at mid declaration

```
QByteArray QByteArray::mid(int pos, int len = -1) const
```

it returns new object, and in this line

```
const char * messageIdBytes = buffer.mid(0, 2);
```

`mid` function returns temporary object *QByteArray*, it is converted to const char* using method

```
QByteArray::operator const char *() const
```

when temporary object is deleted, your pointer is dangling. Then you are reading junk data.

One thing, in this line

```
buffer.mid(2, 4); // should be 2 as second argument, this is not index but length
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. I still have much to learn. :D